# DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body message_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'premium')" is not snowflake

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I'm coding a premium system in discord.js v14, and I've finish everything but there's an error occurred.

There's the code to redeem premium code:

```js
await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

        try {
            let user = await premiumUser.findOne({ Id: interaction.user.id });

            let code = interaction.options.get('code').value;
            console.log(`>${code}<`);

            if (user && user.isPremium) {
                return await interaction.editReply({
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setColor(`Red`)
                            .setTitle(`Error:`)
                            .setDescription(`You're already a premium user.`)
                            .setTimestamp(),
                    ],
                });
            } else {
                const premium = await premiumCode.findOne({
                    code: code.toUpperCase(),
                });

                if (premium) {
                    const expires = moment(premium.expiresAt).format(
                        "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss"
                    );

                    user.isPremium = true;
                    user.premium.redeemedBy.push(interaction.user.id);
                    user.premium.redeemedAt = Date.now();
                    user.premium.expiresAt = premium.expiresAt;
                    user.premium.plan = premium.plan;

                    user = await user.save({ new: true }).catch(console.error);
                    client.userSettings.set(interaction.user.id, user);
                    await premium.deleteOne().catch(console.error);

                    return interaction.editReply({
                        embeds: [
                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                .setColor(`Random`)
                                .setDescription(`You have successfully redeemed the premium!`)
                                .addFields({
                                    name: 'Expires At',
                                    value: expires,
                                }),
                        ],
                    });
                } else {
                    return interaction.editReply({
                        embeds: [
                            new EmbedBuilder()
                                .setColor(`Red`)
                                .setTitle(`Error:`)
                                .setDescription(`This code is invalid. Please try again with a valid code.`),
                        ],
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            await interaction.editReply(err);
            console.error(err);
        }
```

And there's the error, I've got 2 types of them:

```js
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
message_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'isPremium')" is not snowflake.
>SIGMA-YQ9T-MPO6-RPLP-PREMIUM<
```

```js
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'isPremium')
    at Object.callback (/home/container/commands/premium/redeem.js:40:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async module.exports (/home/container/events/interactionCreate/handleCommands.js:102:9)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/handlers/eventHandler.js:21:17)
>SIGMA-YQ9T-MPO6-RPLP-PREMIUM<
```

I tried many ways and search the similar error on stake overflow to fix but didn't work, please help me

It's a premium system in discord.js. An error occurred while I execute `/redeem` command, and I don't know and cannot find out where the problem is and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In your if statement, `user && user.isPremium` will return `false` whenever `user` is falsey or they are not premium. However, in your `else` block, you only infer that the `user` is not premium and have yet to handle a `null` user. Log `user` to see what it returns, then add a separate line of code that checks for `user` being null.